# Is there a Spring version matrix of sub-projects/components?

Tags: spring

Is there someplace that lists which version of a Spring project works with a given version of the Spring Core framework?

For example if I am using Spring Core 3.2.7, what version of Spring security can I use?

- If I use a lot of these components, then I would need to look each up in the maven pom or gradle build. It would be nice to be able look it up quickly.
- Even so, looking it up only tells me that Spring Security 3.2.0 was built with Spring Core 3.2.6.
- Does that mean it will work with Spring Core 3.2.7 or do I need to downgrade my version of Core?

Is there a Matrix that lists versions of the Spring Projects per the Spring Core version?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After looking everywhere and not finding what I wanted, I compiled this matrix from the source code.

I am confident that it is accurate as of today.

I have posted the matrix on the [Spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/743821-spring-version-matrix-of-components) also, as it has a better table display (and it displays in a readable format on Mobile devises).

```
╔════════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╗
║     Framework      ║  4.1.0   ║   4.0.5   ║   4.0.4   ║   4.0.3   ║      4.0.2       ║   4.0.1   ║   4.0.0   ║    3.2.9    ║ 3.2.8 ║   3.2.7   ║    3.2.6    ║    3.2.5    ║   3.2.4   ║   3.2.3   ║   3.2.2   ║    3.2.1    ║   3.2.0   ║    3.1.4    ║   3.1.3   ║  3.1.2   ║   3.1.1   ║   3.1.0   ║   3.0.7   ║   3.0.6   ║   3.0.5   ║   3.0.4   ║   3.0.3   ║  3.0.2   ║   3.0.1   ║   3.0.0    ║ 2.5.6.SEC03 ║ 2.5.6.SEC02 ║ 2.5.6.SEC01 ║   2.5.6   ║
╠════════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╣
║ release date       ║ 3-Aug-14 ║ 20-May-14 ║ 1-May-14  ║ 27-Mar-14 ║ 25-Mar-14        ║ 27-Jan-14 ║ 12-Dec-13 ║ 20-May-14   ║       ║ 27-Jan-14 ║ 12-Dec-13   ║ 6-Nov-13    ║ 6-Aug-13  ║ 21-May-13 ║ 14-Mar-13 ║ 24-Jan-13   ║ 13-Dec-12 ║ 23-Jan-13   ║ 31-Oct-12 ║ 7-Jul-12 ║ 16-Feb-12 ║ 13-Dec-11 ║ 23-Dec-11 ║ 19-Aug-11 ║ 20-Oct-10 ║ 8/19/2010 ║ 6/15/2010 ║ 4/2/2010 ║ 2/18/2010 ║ 12/16/2009 ║ 9/9/2011    ║ 6/18/2010   ║ 4/22/2009   ║ 11/1/2008 ║
║                    ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Spring Projects    ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ AMQP               ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║ 1.3.4 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.2.2       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.1.4a    ║           ║ 1.1.0     ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Batch              ║          ║ 3.0.0     ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 2.2.7       ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║ 2.2.6     ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║ 2.1.9     ║
║ Batch Admin        ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.3.0.BUILD ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║ 1.3.0.M1    ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║ 1.2.1     ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Boot               ║          ║ 1.1.0.RC1 ║           ║ 1.0.3     ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Cassandra     ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0       ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Column        ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║ 1.3.0     ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Commons       ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.8.0       ║ 1.7.2 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.6.5       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.6.5     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Couchbase     ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.1.0       ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0.M2    ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Elasticsearch ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0       ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0.BUILD ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Gemfire       ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.4.0       ║       ║           ║             ║ 1.3.3       ║           ║           ║ 1.3.2     ║             ║           ║             ║ 1.2.2     ║ 1.2.1    ║ 1.1.2     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data JDBC          ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data JPA           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.6.0       ║ 1.5.2 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.4.5       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.4.5     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data MongoDB       ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.5.0       ║ 1.4.2 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.3.5       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.3.5     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Neo4j         ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 3.1.0       ║ 3.0.2 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 2.3.5       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 2.3.5     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Redis         ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.2.1     ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.3.0       ║ 1.2.1 ║           ║ 1.2.0.BUILD ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.1.1       ║           ║ 1.0.2    ║ 1.0.1     ║ 1.0.0     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data REST          ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 2.1.0       ║ 2.0.2 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0    ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Data Solr          ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║ 1.2.0       ║ 1.1.2 ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Hadoop             ║          ║ 2.0.0.RC4 ║ 2.0.0.RC3 ║ 2.0.0.RC2 ║ 2.0.0.RC1        ║           ║ 2.0.0.M5  ║             ║       ║           ║ 2.0.0.M5    ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.0.2     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Integration        ║          ║ 4.0.2     ║           ║ 4.0.0     ║                  ║ 4.0.0.M3  ║ 4.0.0.M2  ║             ║ 3.0.3 ║           ║ 3.0.2       ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║ 2.2.3     ║          ║           ║           ║ 2.1.6c    ║           ║ 2.0.5     ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ LDAP               ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║ 2.0.2 ║           ║             ║             ║ 2.0.0     ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║ 1.3.2     ║           ║           ║ 1.3.1     ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║ 1.3.1       ║           ║
║ Mobile             ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║ 1.1.1 ║           ║             ║             ║ 1.1.0     ║           ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.2       ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Roo                ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║ 1.2.5     ║          ║ 1.2.2     ║ 1.2.1     ║           ║ 1.2.0     ║ 1.1.5     ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Scala              ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║ 1.0.0.RC1 ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Security           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║ 3.2.4 / 4.0.0.M1 ║ 3.2.1     ║ 3.2.0     ║             ║ 3.2.4 ║           ║ 3.2.0       ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║ 3.1.4     ║ 3.1.0     ║           ║           ║ 3.0.7     ║          ║ 3.0.2     ║ 3.0.1      ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Security OAuth     ║          ║           ║           ║ 2.0.1     ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║ 2.0.0.BUILD ║           ║ 2.0.0.M2  ║           ║             ║           ║             ║ 1.0.5     ║ 1.0.4    ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Shell              ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.1.0.RC3 ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0    ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Social             ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.1.0     ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║ 1.1.0.M4  ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.3       ║           ║          ║           ║ 1.0.2     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Social Facebook    ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.1.1     ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║ 1.1.0.M4  ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.3    ║           ║ 1.0.1     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Social GitHub      ║          ║           ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0.M4         ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║ 1.0.0.M4  ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Social LinkedIn    ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.0.1     ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║ 1.0.0.RC3 ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Social TripIt      ║          ║           ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0.BUILD ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Social Twitter     ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.1.0     ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║ 1.1.0.M4  ║           ║             ║           ║ 1.0.5       ║           ║ 1.0.4    ║           ║ 1.0.2     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
║ Web Flow           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║ 2.4.0            ║           ║ 2.3.4     ║             ║       ║           ║ 2.3.2       ║             ║           ║           ║           ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║ 2.3.1     ║           ║           ║           ║ 2.3.0     ║ 2.2.1     ║ 2.1.1     ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║ 2.0.9       ║ 2.0.7     ║
║ Web Services       ║          ║ 2.2.0     ║           ║           ║                  ║           ║           ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║ 2.1.4     ║           ║ 2.1.3     ║             ║           ║             ║ 2.1.2     ║          ║ 2.1.1     ║ 2.0.4     ║           ║ 2.0.3     ║ 2.0.2     ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║ 1.5.10    ║
║ XD                 ║          ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0.M7  ║                  ║           ║ 1.0.0.M5  ║             ║       ║           ║             ║             ║           ║           ║ 1.0.0.M3  ║             ║           ║             ║           ║          ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║          ║           ║            ║             ║             ║             ║           ║
╚════════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: In case you are wondering I used the nice Senseful Solutions [Format Text as a Table tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to make the table.

Comment: There really needs to be a maintained authority version of this table.

Comment: @Stewart that would be awesome but when I asked the Spring devs they had no interest and told me to just use the latest. I have stopped using Spring and so I have stopped updating this table. At this point it only serves to map the really old versions. I had to go through the pom.xml files to see which version matched what and I don't have time to do that anymore.

Comment: Is there any way you can make such a conversation public? I think it shows contempt and arrogance!  On one project I've recently had to downgrade my `spring-core` version from 4.x to 3.2.x, which in turn caused code changes, just because I was using Spring Batch Admin and there were various version conflicts. It's a battle that just seems unnecessary.

Comment: I would love to share it but I don't even remember where I had it. But dealing with old versions is why I wrote this up.