# Which version of Spring Security should I use with spring core 3.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I am using Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE in my project and I want to add the Spring Security Framework, and I found after some researches in the Internet that there a problem of compatibility between Spring Core and Spring Security

my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
<!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you chenge to spring core 3.2.6?  if yess you cen use the spring security version 3.2.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Spring version matrix of sub-projects/components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361599/is-there-a-spring-version-matrix-of-sub-projects-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well my current working project is on:
spring-core-3.2.13.RELEASE
spring-security-3.1.0.RC3

Also, Older projects have been working on ;
org.springframework.core-3.0.6.RELEASE
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RC3

Hope this helps you to make a choice.

Comment: I found in the Internet that the Spring 3.2.x dont make problems with Spring Security so i will choose Spring Security 3.2.7