# Which spring security version is compatible with spring 3.2.8

Tags: spring, spring-security

Please what is the compatible release version for Spring Security for Spring 3.2.8 release ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Spring version matrix of sub-projects/components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361599/is-there-a-spring-version-matrix-of-sub-projects-components)

Answer (score 2):

There is little dependancy between Spring Security versions and Spring Framework versions. I have  already used Spring Security 3.1.x with Spring Framework 3.1.x and 3.2.x.

If you have no reason to do differently (portability of code) you should choose the more recent *General Available* version that is compatible with your other components.

[Doc for latest GA (4.0.1)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven) says that it *builds against Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE, but should work with 4.0.x* => no good.

[Doc for previous GA (3.2.7)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) says that is *builds against Spring Framework 3.2.13.RELEASE, but is also tested against Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE*

It would be my first choice, but if you use maven, you will have to control what is actually imported via transitive dependancy and eventually force 3.2.8 versions for all used Spring Framework components to avoid mixing different versions, or better upgrade to 3.2.13 since it is only a patch level different version.

Of course, you can also make use of the fact that previous Spring Security version (3.2.6) explicitely *builds against Spring Framework 3.2.8.RELEASE*, as said by @zeisi

Answer (score 1):

According to the Docs it would be 3.2.6, see [Spring Security Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom)