# What is the compatible version of Spring Security with Spring 4.3.0?

Tags: java, spring, jar, version, compatibility

Which version of Spring Security is compatible with Spring version 4.3.0.

**My JARs are as follows:**

- spring-aop-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-jdbc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-orm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-oxm-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tx-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar

**With Security JARs:**

- spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Spring version matrix of sub-projects/components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361599/is-there-a-spring-version-matrix-of-sub-projects-components)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation for Spring Security 4.2.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom) says that the current Spring Security version 4.2.x is compatible with Spring 4.3.26 and 4.0.x.

For Spring Security 3.2.5 you should use Spring 4.0.2 ([doc for 3.2.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#get-spring-security)).

Comment: In addition, I must use http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd in my security-xml right ?

Comment: I'ver never used this xsd file, but I think its version should match the artifacts version.

Answer (score 1):

(Latest Version)

UPDATES - Spring Security 5.6.0

Spring Security 5.6.0 was released on 15 November 2021. This is a maintenance/bug fix release.

Spring Security 5.6.0 is compatible with Spring Framework 5.3.13

If you want to use the latest version, update your Maven POM file to use the compatible versions below

```
<springframework.version>5.3.13</springframework.version>
 
<springsecurity.version>5.6.0</springsecurity.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep coming back to asking myself which spring-security version is "compatible" with which spring-framework version.

There's this [Spring Security docs page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html), that informs on that subject, distinguishing between Spring Boot / Non-Spring-Boot projects combined with Maven / Gradle.

For Non-Spring-Boot projects the recommended way is to use the BOM (bill of material) artifact.

- details for [Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html#getting-maven-no-boot)
- details for [Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html#_gradle_without_spring_boot)

Spring Boot utilizes this BOM too, so you don't have to set anything specifically there.

You can also find the same information for a specific spring-security version, e.g. for 5.1.13 it's: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#get-spring-security

which contains version specific details. Just go to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs and find your version.